# Nomethoderror trying to use Devise with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm following a guide on Devise and I am currently stuck with this:

```
`NoMethodError in TasksController#new undefined method `tasks' for nil:NilClass
```

Task.rb

```
  class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
  end
```

User.rb

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   has_many :tasks
 end
```

TaskController.rb

```
def new
  @task = current_user.tasks.build
end

def create
  @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)
end
```

**DB - Schema.rb**

```
create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "content"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
 end
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you authenticated?

Comment: Authenticated how?

Comment: You were absolutely right, thank you so much Hasmukh!

Comment: @Drixzy, Great, You can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Error message says: `nil.tasks`

It means the `User` class object is not created.

Try to login. Once you are logged in, the error will be resolved.